# Call a class constructor with parameter inside the parent class

Tags: c#, .net, class, constructor

I have this class as you can see :

```
   public class mybaseclass
    {
        public string token = "";
        private readonly HttpContextAccessor iHTTP;

        public mybaseclass([FromServices]HttpContextAccessor IHTTP)
        {
            //this.httpContext = httpContext;
            iHTTP = IHTTP;
        }
        public mybaseclass()
        {
           
        }
        
      
        protected Task<HttpRequestMessage> CreateHttpRequestMessageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           // var t = null;
            try
            {
               // iHTTP.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[key]
               var t = iHTTP.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Authorization"];
                if (t == null)
                {
                    token = t;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception aaa)
            {

            }
            
                var msg = new HttpRequestMessage();
            // SET THE BEARER AUTH TOKEN
            msg.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            return Task.FromResult(msg);
        }
    }
```

And this class is called in this class :

```
public partial class Default1Client : mybaseclass, IDefault1Client
    {
        private string _baseUrl = "";
        private System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings> _settings;

        public Default1Client(string baseUrl)
        {
            BaseUrl = baseUrl;
            _settings = new System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings>(CreateSerializerSettings);
        }
// other part of code 
}
```

My problem is when I call Default1Client,the class calls the mybaseclass constructor that doesn't have any parameters ,but I need the constructor with `httpcontextaccessor`to be called

Comment: How exactly are you creating an instance of `Default1Client `? Is it being injected or are you using `new`?

Comment: @JohnWu It's injected into my controller ,And I set the injection in the startup file

Comment: So how are you populating `baseUrl` then? Can you show us the code/config that does this?

Comment: @JohnWu  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
           // services.AddScoped<IDefault1Client, Default1Client>();
            services.AddScoped<IDefault1Client>(provider =>
            {
                return new Default1Client("https://localhost:44381");
            });
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your constructor to pass it through:

```
public Default1Client(string baseUrl, HttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(contextAccessor)
{
    //etc....
```

And populate it when you register:

```
services.AddScoped<IDefault1Client>(provider => { return new Default1Client
(
    "localhost:44381", 
    provider.GetService(typeof(HttpContextAccessor)) as HttpContextAccesor
)});
```

Comment: thank you .I have changed my code as you said .But again the HttpContextAccessor  is null

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and/or log the value returned by `provider.GetService(typeof(HttpContextAccessor))`? It could be the problem is outside of the code you have shown us.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to specify the parameters, we can inject them using a function that will get the httpContextAccessor from your baseurl:

```
    // you can use a function call to get the accessor
    public Default1Client(string baseUrl) : mybaseclass(getHttpContextAccessor(baseUrl))
```

If you pass it the parameters that will correspond to `httpcontextaccessor` the constructor which takes parameters will be called.

Comment: so how should I inject  httpcontextaccessor  into default1client ?

Comment: You can modify the DefaultClient constructor to take it as a parameter or have a function method that transforms the baseUrl and returns the httpcontextaccessor. I updated my answer to reflect this.